No driver available for MediaTek MT7927 WiFi or Bluetooth on Ubuntu 24.10 with kernel 6.11
I've purchased a new mother board (ASUS ROG Strix X870E-E Gaming WiFi) with a WiFi 7 card MediaTek MT7927 and I can see that there's no driver available for it neither in the kernel, nor in the list of additional drivers. Does anybody have any suggestions? I did see that the driver for mt7925 was recently introduced into kernel.
Thank you in advance

Sadly, MediaTek still have not published a Linux driver for MT7927, despite launching it well over a year ago.
Depending on how accessible the wifi card is on your motherboard, you may wish to consider changing it out for something that does have Linux drivers, like their MT7925.
